# I'm trying to create ruby inline bot for Telegram bot 2.0, but it shows nothing in inline result

Tags: ruby, telegram-bot

Telegram returns me *{"ok"=>true, "result"=>true}* and even shows button "switch to PM", but nothing appears as the answers result. The only thing that could be broken here from my point of view is the way I'm preparing array for results to be send. Could anyone help me?

Here's code example:

```
Telegram::Bot::Client.run(token) do |bot|
  bot.listen do |message|

    case message
    when Telegram::Bot::Types::Message
      puts "Message @#{message.from.username}: #{message.text}"
      bot.api.send_message(chat_id: message.chat.id, text: "I am only inline bot for now" )
    when Telegram::Bot::Types::InlineQuery
      puts " InlineQuery @#{message.from.username}: #{message.query} and #{message.id}"

      results = [ JSON.parse('{"type":"article", "id":"0", "title":"Cool Blog", "message_text":"I am the author of this bot, please visit my blog"}'), JSON.parse('{"type":"article", "id":"1", "title":"Cool Blog", "message_text":"I am the author of this bot, please visit my blog"}')] 
      puts bot.api.answer_inline_query(inline_query_id: message.id, results: results, switch_pm_text:"PM me please", cache_time: 86400)
    end

  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just update gem to version '0.5' and it should work properly gem `install 'telegram-bot-ruby'`